# How to set timezone in jest tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In my application i use a specific timezone (UK). To run the tests i use `"test": "TZ=UTC jest`. In my code i created some function that uses Intl api.

```js
const Date = (d, opt = {}) => {

  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'en-GB',
    {
      ...opt,
      timeZone: 'Europe/London'
    }
  ).format(new Date(d))
}
```

The issue is next: when i run the test with `npm run test` the results are different, if i run a single test locally. For example if a run a separate test in my react application and i expect the next date `08:00` the code works, but if i run the code using `npm run test` the code does not give the expected value, instead gives `10:00`. The issue appears when i set do this in my test:

```js
test('It should return time', () => {
  const n = new Date()
  n.setHours(10)
  n.setMinutes(00)

  const r = getD(n)
  expect(r).toEqual('10:30') // expect 08:00
})
```

I understand that the results are different because when i run the tests using `npm run test` it uses UTC, and when i run them locally the tests uses the correct date. But how to avoid this issue and to get every time the correct time? 
 Note: UK time is behind with 2 hours in my situation.
 PS: i don't use momentjs

Comment: How are you running a single test locally, if _not_ via `npm run-script`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, web storm has this feature. You can run only one  test if you want.

Comment: And when it does so, it applies some settings (might be using a different Node interpreter, adding some env vars, ...) - double-check what's in the Run/Debug Configuration for the single test, evidently _something_ is different between your test runs. What if you run the same single test _outside_ WebStorm (to help narrow down whether it's the test environment or your tests aren't independent)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the time is different because when i run `test": "TZ=UTC jest` it use UTC time, but if i run it locally it uses UK timezone. But i want to get rid of this and to get every time UK timezone. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Use the functionality you're already using, but set it to the timezone you actually want?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, to change tests?